# How can I improve my SVM algorithm by creating innovation?

Tags: matlab, dataset, svm, prediction

I used the svm algorithm to predict patients' survival time.
I did the programming with matlab. Now I'm going to increase the computational accuracy by doing something innovative (like using another algorithm to select data or combining it with another algorithm).
I also need a patient database (like the Corona patient database).
The goal is to predict patient survival.

Comment: If someone else tells you what to do you aren't being innovative (they are).

Comment: you have no database? If you are new to machine learning, you shouldn't start with combining to algorithms. First have a look at *hyperparameter optimization* of SVMs. You can just activate MATLAB's build in function...

Comment: @David .You are right. I have little time to do the project.

Comment: @max.Thank you for your answer. I decided to use data selection with the help of another algorithm to reduce the error. Of course, I do not know which algorithm is more suitable?